# How can I disallow the changing of a parent?

Tags: unity

I want to disable [transform.SetParent(Transform)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) for a particular GameObject.

I am not sure where to start, so it is really difficult to show what I have tried.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to prevent that, however you can get a call when the parent transform changes and set it back to the correct value.

```
Transform m_DesiredParent;
void Awake()
{
    m_DesiredParent = transform.parent;
}

void OnTransformParentChanged()
{
    if(transform.parent != m_DesiredParent)
    {
          transform.SetParent(m_DesiredParent);
          Debug.LogError("Cant change this parent, setting back to desired parent");
    }
}
```

Biggest downside is that you cant control if the position/rotation/scale will be set back to the same value since there is no way of knowing whether the call that changed it saved its local position/rotation/scale or its world/position/rotation/scale

Comment: Thanks! This will work for me. Didnt know I could do this

Answer (score 3):

It is very possible(with a quick refactoring), and you dont need to know the actual type, worry about deriving or need to instantiate every gameObejct manually in code. A simple trick with [extension methods](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/extension-methods) will do: just "add" a field and extension method to the `GameObject` class:

```
public static class GameObjectExtensions
{
    private static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<GameObject, bool> _canSet = new ConditionalWeakTable<GameObject, bool>();

    public static void ChangeCanSetParent(this GameObject go, bool value) 
    {
         _canSet.Remove(go);
         _canSet.Add(go, value);
    }

    public static void TrySetParent (this GameObject go, Transform transform) 
    {
         bool can;
         if(!_canSet.TryGetValue(go, out can) || can) 
            go.SetParent(transform);
         else {
          //or just ignore it
          throw new ApplicationException("method SetParent() is disabled on this GameObject.");
         }
    }
}
```

Now just find/replace all(or simply just where it matters) occurrences of `SetParent` with your new custom `TrySetParent`, usage:

```
GameObject player; //can set safely from editor, it IS actually "normal" game object
//originally player.SetParent()
player.TrySetParent(transform); //will work
player.ChangeCanSetParent(false); //disable it
player.TrySetParent(transform); //will throw
```

while it does not technically disable original `SetParent`, it is clean solution with backwards compatibility and without worrying anything in "user" code, or unexpected behavior and errors caused by not testing for/casting to actual type.

Comment: This is going in my extensions. I dont know why I will need to disable Setparent(), but I'm collecting it anyways. Bravo sir.

Comment: Noob question my ' System.Runtime.CompilerServices' does not contain a definition of ConditionalWeakTable what am  I missing here ?

Comment: Thanks. I like this idea. Unfortunately, it won't work for me. I'm writing open source software, and changing the parent breaks my software.

Comment: @UriPopov that is strange error, have you tried googling it? Does it require reference to an assembly perhaps? You can could change the `ConditionalWeakTable` for a `Dictionary` or a custom implementation of some weak reference collection. But a warning: if you use plain dictionary you need to unregister the objects manually, otherwise you may cause memory leaks.

Comment: Well the things is that `ConditionalWeakTable` is in .Net4 and unity uses a sub-set of .net3.5. So when I reference `System.Rumtime.CompileServices ` there is simply no implementation of it. Are you using this type in a unity3d project ?

Comment: @UriPopov the [WeakReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.90).aspx) class should be part of .NET 3.5 already, so I d suggest using a dictionary of weak references (there are even some examples on the documentation page) instead. Or find ready-to-go implementation on google. For example, [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/ConditionalWeakTable.cs) appear to be the "official" implementation.

Comment: @wondra your suggestion would work if I was the one calling the method. But this software is for others to use, and I can't stop them from trying to change the parent directly. Best I can do is to check every frame if they have, and stop it like that

Comment: @Evorlor good point, did not understand you previous comment. But keep in mind, the users want to use your code and follow your API, not crash it. If you cannot have this assumption about your users, the only possibility is code injection through reflection, but one also may argue that if *you* injected something so *they* can as well.

Answer (score 2):

No, not really, as the method is not virtual.

The closest reasonable approach is to derive from `GameObject` and implement a *new* `SetParent` method:

```
public new void SetParent (Transform transform) {
  throw new NotSupportedException("I'm afraid I can't do that.");
}
```

However, this will only fail at runtime and even then only if you call `SetParent` through an instance that is of the type of your subclass. That is, this code:

```
MyGameObject instance = new MyGameObject();
instance.SetParent(...);
```

will throw when `SetParent` is called. However this (likely very common) code:

```
GameObject instance = new MyGameObject();
instance.SetParent(...);
```

will not throw, because `SetParent` isn't virtual.

---

I suspect that whatever you're trying to accomplish by preventing `SetParent` from getting called, you're going to have to try doing so at a higher level, but without more information it's hard to suggest what you should try.

Comment: [I'm sorry Dave...](https://youtu.be/ARJ8cAGm6JE?t=1m4s)

Comment: You could also do something similar in an editor script (it before runtime). I've been using a similar method to check and lock positions.

Comment: @null Can you post an answer explaining how? I don't actually use Unity so I'm only tackling this from a C# language perspective, but your solution may work better for the asker.

Comment: @null if you have a suggestion better than checking every frame if the current parent is different from the parent the previous frame, I'd be very interested to hear it

Comment: @JoshPetrie, sorry I'm not more helpful, but a colleague recommends looking into MonoBehaviour.OnValidate, which fires when something is changed in the inspector: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html